# Adobe Muse Dynamic Content Change

Tags: html, dynamic, muse

I am making the website of an internet radio station and i want to use Adobe Muse for its simplicity in design. What i want to do is have the header and footer not refreshing when you go for example from the home page to the about page. I just want the content of the page to change. That is because i wanna have the radios music player in the header so that it won't refresh and stop playing when you change sites. Something like this: http://www.rockharadio.gr/
Is there any way to do it using Adobe Muse? If not what should i do? I am totally newbie when it comes to jQuery or AJAX.
Thanks ind advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible... 
so the thing is you would just need to create a One-Page Scrollable Site... just try using "pinning and anchoring" to automatically help you scroll on home page or about page.. this pages are just in the one page (try to watch this [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngm5quHtJI4))

just try search on google or youtube about the anchor... you would love it I promise!

I just dont know how to import the radio music player... Hope it Helps :)

Comment: Although not what i was looking for this tutorial is pretty good and i'm sure i will use it in the future. I managed to make the site i wanted using JS. In case anyone wonders here's the guide i found in order to do it: [link](http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/)